# how to format type string as code in html

Tags: javascript, html, ejs

I have this code which is returned as a part of an object, and is stored as type string. this is the way it is stored:

```
def helloWorld():    print("hello World")helloWorld()
```

as you can see, it is all in one string on one line.

In html, i am accessing this like so:

```
<textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="output" id="exampleInputPassword1" style="height: 300px;" readonly><%= recordData.output %></textarea>
```

now, I want to be able to format `<%= recordData.output %>` as code so that it isn't in one line. is this possible either through `html` or `js`?

Comment: That code seems to be a piece of python code, an incorrect one at that. Is it not feasible to put `\n` characters in the code string?

Comment: @cSharp right, it is a piece of python code. what i am doing is storing code in my mongodb and then send the code to the front-end, where I would ideally like to format it --dynamically-- so that it can look like code.

Comment: Yes. The best approach would be to save it with the `\n` newline characters when you store the code in your db.